# Setting up a log directory

Tags: php, mkdir, dirname

I want to create a new folder if there isn't already one created. In order to do that I wrote:

```
//Set up the log directory

if(is_dir(dirname(LOG_PATH))) {

} else {
    mkdir(LOG_PATH, 0777, true);
    echo "Directory created. ". LOG_PATH ."<br />";
}
```

LOG_PATH = E:\xampp\htdocs\photo\logs\

There is a photo folder, but there is no logs folder (I want to create that folder).

Am I missing something, because the if statement here is true. It shouldn't be.

Comment: it is possible that `mkdir` fails. Check it's return value.

Comment: If I put mkdir(LOG_PATH, 0777, true); first (in true case), then it goes ahead and creates the folder, so the syntax should be ok. I believe it's the logic here that is at fault. My guess is, I wrongly wrote the path. Maybe I shouldn't use the '\' at the very end?

Comment: If you're on linux, I suggest to simply use your syslog engine to log everything.

Comment: No, sadly I'm on Windows :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirname(LOG_PATH)` returns the parent of the `LOG_PATH` (`E:\xampp\htdocs\photo`), so your `if` statement is true when the `photo` folder exists, not when the `logs` folder exists.

You should modify the condition to be:

```
if (is_dir(LOG_PATH)) {

} else {
    mkdir(LOG_PATH, 0777, true);
    echo "Directory created. ". LOG_PATH ."<br />";
}
```

And, if you are leaving the first branch empty, just negate the condition:

```
if (!is_dir(LOG_PATH)) {
    mkdir(LOG_PATH, 0777, true);
    echo "Directory created. ". LOG_PATH ."<br />";
}
```

And by the way, the `mkdir` call may fail if you don't have permissions to create a new folder there, so you should check if that fails or not:

```
if (!is_dir(LOG_PATH)) {
    if (mkdir(LOG_PATH, 0777, true)) {
        echo "Directory created. ". LOG_PATH ."<br />";
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Can't create folder " . LOG_PATH);
    }
}
```

Comment: From now on I hate dirname function :) Thanks, it did the trick!

Comment: Thanks again! I'm focusing on windows machine now, so it shouldn't be a problem with folder permissions, but I will keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

The 'mkdir' function doesn't function correctly on Windows when the path
contains forward slashes. The part of the path with the forward slashes
doesn't get created.

mkdir('c:/a/b/c/d', 0775, true);

You get the error message:
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

Please use backslashes under Windows or use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

mkdir('c:\a\b\c\d', 0775, true);
mkdir('c:'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'a'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'b'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'c'.
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'d', 0775, true);

Comment: he is using backslashes, so that's not the problem here, but the tip about using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a good one.

Comment: My path is using backslashes as shown in the original message. My LOG_PATH definition: defined('LOG_PATH') ? null : define ('LOG_PATH', 'E:'.DS.'xampp'.DS.'htdocs'.DS.'photo'.DS.'logs'.DS); where DS is: defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);